# count number using random number rand()

Tags: c, random

I'm learning C and find `rand()` is very strange, maybe due to its randomness :p

I've the following code, it always output 1, is there any problem? How would you modify the code to make it do the job?

Cheers,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double rand_double()
{
    double ret = (double)rand();
    return ret/(RAND_MAX+1);
}

int sample_geometric_rv(double p)
{
    double q;
    int n = 0;
    do
    {
        q = rand_double();
        n++;
    } while (q >= p);
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int ans = sample_geometric_rv(0.1);
    printf("Output %d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to seed the random number generator **ONCE**. Use `srand()` with a different value everytime you want a different sequence.

In the absence of a seeding, it is as if you had issued a `srand(1);`

Tipically, the RNG is seeded in `main()` with the current time as initialization value. The current time as returned by `time()` is almost guaranteed to be different in every run of the program (it changes once per second).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(0));
    /* rest of program; no more calls to srand() */
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you initialize the RNG with the same number, you get the same sequence. This can be interesting, for example, to repeat the data.

Note too that on different computers, the same initialization number does not need to generate the same numbers.

Comment: Remember an important point: only one `srand()` call per program.

Answer (score 1):

RAND_MAX here is very likely (2^31)-1 (maximum 32-bit signed integer), so adding 1 causes it to wrap and become negative, which in turn means that p will exceed q for any positive value of p. Change this:

```
 return ret/(RAND_MAX+1);
```

to this:

```
 return ret/((double)RAND_MAX+1.0);
```

Seeding the RNG (as previously suggested) is also highly recommended.

Comment: Are you saying the cast is not needed because the `1.0` will cause the entire statement to be evaluated as a `double`? The cast is what allows the divisor to be incremented beyond the limits of its default data type.

Comment: yep. without the cast you have `int+double` and the int will be converted to double implicitly before the addition; with the cast (an explicit conversion) you have `double+double` and no implicit conversion. But casts are ugly and seldom needed.

Comment: I'll agree with the ugly bit. I couldn't remember which way the evaluation would go (and have actually encountered compilers that would evaluate `int+double` as `int`) so I figured I'd be safe.

Comment: `6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions` and `6.5.6 Additive operators` cover the conversions used in the expression `RAND_MAX + 1.0` :)